# How does routing know where the file is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My VS project has the following folder and files:

```
~\Controllers
  \AccountController.cs
  \HomeController.cs
...
~\Data
  \AccountController.cs

...
~\App_Start
  \RouteConfig.cs
  \WebApiConfig.cs
```

`WebApiConfig.cs` contains:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
     }
}
```

`~\Data\AcccountController.cs` contains:

```
namespace myApp.Data
{
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetUser(int id)
        {
            //...
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

When I make a http call to `/api/Account/GetUser`, the call is routed to the `GetUser` method shown above.  What in all of the above or any configuration file tells the server to take the action from this particular file?  What if `~/Controllers/AccountController.cs` also contain a method of the same name?

Answer (score 0):

It is called convention over configuration.

Comment: Do you mean the string fragment `api` in "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" must match the string fragment `Api` in the base class `ApiController`?